# using css to allow a div to grow in width to a certain predetermined limit

Tags: html, css

Is it possible using CSS to have a panel that can grow in width as the content grows up to a certain predetermined limit?
Many thanks,
James

---

see here: http://jamesradford.net/me.htm

I need the 'LEFT COLUMN' to fill 50% of the 600px panel when there's sufficient content to fill the 50%. So in this example, the left column with much more content would grow to width=300px before vertically wrapping. thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`max-width`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#min-max-widths) to determine the maximum width to which the `div` (or other `block` or `inline-block` element) can stretch.

You can also specify a `min-width` to define the *minimum* width a `block` (or `inline-block`) element can have:

```
p, div {
    min-width: 20em;
    max-width: 50%;
}
```

My personal usage is to specify *one* of the attributes as an absolute value (`px`, `em`, `pt`) and the other as a percentage of the screen (`%`) or parent element.

Comment: my element that needs to grow to a set length limit floats to the left.  Is this still possible?

Comment: @James: I can't think why not, so it should be.

Comment: @JamesRadford Was your question answered to your satisfaction? Or are there outstanding concerns or questions? If it's been answered to your needs please consider accepting one of the posted answers (not necessarily this one, but whichever best answers your question).

Answer (score 1):

You can set a `max-width` property within the style

Comment: If it doesn't work then just post a link here and I will have a look and find out why.

Comment: @JamesRadford - sorry, I forgot to tag you in the last comment

Answer (score 1):

based on the new information and link here's a suggestion.. use `max-width` as suggested on the left column, then set the column "gap" as a right margin to this div too.. then by setting `overflow: hidden` on the right column it will automatically take up whatever space is left over for it once other restrictions have been taken care of

### working example : [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/Sf6nh/)

uncomment some of the text in left column to make the left div grow

Code:
**HTML**

```
<div id="Container">

    <div class="leftCol">
        <h3>Left Column</h3>  
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi</p>
        <!--
        tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
        -->
    </div>

    <div class="ColumnGap">
        <h3>RIGHT COLUMN</h3>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#Container {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    float: left;
    width: 600px;
}

.leftCol {
    float: left;
    background-color: #444;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    max-width: 298px;  /* took off 2px for border - optional */
    margin-right: 10px; /* this is the "column gap" */
}

.ColumnGap {
    overflow: hidden; /* this column will auto adjust to space left  */
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

### Added jQuery IE6 solution:

```
<!--[if lte IE 6]>aded jQuery solution for IE6
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

          $(".leftCol").each(function() {

           //Get the width of the left column
           var width = $(this).width();

           // if it's width is greater than 298px, fix it at 298px
           if (width > 298) {
             $(this).css("width", "298px");
           }

         });

});
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Yes you're right,  it's because IE6 doesn't support `max-width` -  even if it did `.ColumnGap` will need `zoom: 1;` set on it to trigger the hasLayout property to true as IE6 doesn't support `overflow: hidden;` for setting hasLayout to true - you will likely need a `max-width` hack for IE6, and a JS one at that, to get IE6 to play ball here.. if you decide to go that route then watch the JS "expression" hacks as they frequently crash IE - if interested let me know and I'll update post with a jQuery workaround for IE6

Comment: sorry to be a pain but please post the workaround with jQuery.  This is really great so far

Comment: @James have added it to the answer, you can feed just that bit of script to IE6 using a conditional comment as I have it in, but it would work for all browsers anyway